# make list of pixels selected by mask

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image and a mask that selects pixels from that image. I want to make a list of these pixels and then do cluster analysis on them using scipy.kmeans.
Is there a better way (eg a function that I don't know of) than this

```
pixels = []
for irow,mrow in zip(img,mask):
    pixels += [pixel for pixel,mbyte in zip(irow,mrow) if mbyte==255]
```

Comment: `pixels = img[mask == 255]` or `pixels = list(img[mask == 255])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) - [boolean or "mask" index array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> img = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
...                 [4, 5, 6]])
>>> mask = np.array([[0, 255, 0],
...                  [255, 0, 0]])
>>> img[mask == 255]
array([2, 4])
```

If you want `list` instead of `numpy.array`, use `list` to conver the result:

```
>>> list(img[mask == 255])
[2, 4]
```

Comment: @HaydonBerrow, You're welcome. Happy Python programming.